# Ball pulling game

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are $16$ red and $15$ white balls in a basket. You and the dealer take turns drawing $2$ random balls from the basket (and do not return it back). If the balls are of different colors, the dealer adds one more white ball to the basket, if both balls are of the same color, then the dealer adds one more red ball to the basket.

You win if the last ball in the basket is white, the dealer wins if the last ball in the basket is red. Estimate the probability of your winning.

$1$ move

Probability of white-white: $\frac{15}{31} \cdot \frac{14}{30}$

Probability of red-red: $\frac{16}{31} \cdot \frac{15}{30}$

So, the probability that a red ball will be added after the first move is: $\frac{15}{31} \cdot \frac{14}{30} + \frac{16}{31} \cdot \frac{15}{30} = \frac{15}{31} $

Probability of white-red: $\frac{16}{31} \cdot \frac{15}{30}$

So, the probability that a white ball will be added after the first move is: $2 \cdot \frac{16}{31} \cdot \frac{15}{30} = \frac{16}{31} $

Mathematical expectation of white balls after the first move:

$15 - 2 \cdot \frac{15}{31} \cdot \frac{14}{30} + \frac{16}{31} \cdot (1-1) = 14 + \frac{17}{31} =  \frac{451}{31}$

Mathematical expectation of red balls after the first move:

$16 - 2 \cdot \frac{16}{31} \cdot \frac{15}{30} + \frac{15}{31} \cdot 1 - \frac{16}{31} \cdot 1  = 15 + \frac{14}{31} =  \frac{479}{31}$

$2$ move

Probability of white-white: $\frac{\frac{451}{31}}{30} \cdot \frac{\frac{451-31}{31}}{29}$

Probability of red-red: $\frac{\frac{479}{31}}{30} \cdot \frac{\frac{479-31}{31}}{29}$

So, the probability that a red ball will be added after the second move is: $\frac{\frac{451}{31}}{30} \cdot \frac{\frac{451-31}{31}}{29} + \frac{\frac{479}{31}}{30} \cdot \frac{\frac{479-31}{31}}{29} = \frac{404012}{29 \cdot 30 \cdot 31^2}$

The probability that a white ball will be added after the second move is: $2 \cdot \frac{\frac{451}{31}}{30} \cdot \frac{\frac{479}{31}}{29} = \frac{432058}{29 \cdot 30 \cdot 31^2}$

Then I can calculate the mathematical expectation of the balls of each color on the second move, and so on, however, there are too many rounds in the game for a direct calculation. It probably needs to do some kind of limit jump or find a recursive dependency, but I'm stuck and having trouble with that.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I'd go by states, labeling the states according to the number of balls of each color.  Work by backwards induction.

Comment: Should say:  looks like a fairly messy computation.  If you don't need an exact answer, maybe simulation is better.

Comment: Does this end after $29$ pairs of draws (before which there were $31-28\times 2+28=3$ balls left so removing two leaves one before one is added) or after $30$ pairs of draws (before which there were $31-29\times 2+29=2$ balls left so removing two leaves zero and one is added to leave one)?

Comment: @Henry, that's a good question!
Unfortunately, there is no specific answer to this in the problem statement. I think there are $30$ comparisons, $2$ balls are taken out, what color they have is determined and as a result $1$ ball is put in the basket and the game ends.

Comment: @lulu, It is assumed that this problem has an analytical solution. (and probably without heavily exhausting calculations).

Comment: Why is that assumed?  I would expect this to be a bit messy, personally.

Comment: This problem is from a list in which all other problems had not very cumbersome solutions. Based on this, I make the assumption that this task is the same. (Unless, of course, the author of the problem did not make any typo in the numbers)

Comment: I mean, maybe there is a trick.  Like that you can decide whether the last two must (or can't) match.  Simulation sounds like a good idea.  Just check to see if you always get the same result.

Comment: Each step has only two possible outcomes. If you have $r$ red and $w$ white, even though there are four possible ways the dealer and player can take balls, the result at the end is either: $r+1$ red and $w-2$ white (with probability $\dfrac{\dbinom{w}{2}}{\dbinom{r+w}{2}}$) or $r-1$ red and $w$ white (with probability $1-\dfrac{\dbinom{w}{2}}{\dbinom{r+w}{2}}$) This should be a major simplifying assumption.

Comment: @SlipEternal There is a parity trick, which I only spotted after doing the full calculation, but it is implied by your comment

Comment: Yeah, there is a simple parity remark that removes the difficulty.  Clever, I didn't spot it until I simulated it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You start off with $31$ balls and each turn you either

- take out two reds and add one red, changing the parity of the number of red balls and leaving the parity of white balls the same
- take out a red and a white and add one white, changing the parity of the number of red balls and leaving the parity of white balls the same
- take out two whites and add one red, changing the parity of the number of red balls and leaving the parity of white balls the same

So the final parities are determined by the initial parities and the total number of pairs removed, making the answer $1$ here (you start with an odd number of white balls so must end with one white) if you stop after after $30$ pairs of draws (before which there were $31−29×2+29=2$ balls left so removing two leaves zero and one is added to leave one, which must be white - in fact that final draw must have been one red and one white and then a white is put in)

Comment: Unfortunately, I only noticed this once I had done the full recursion.  Just for the record, I think that after $27$ rounds the probability of three reds and one white is about $0.50020284$ and of one red and three whites $0.49979716$, so after $28$ rounds the probability of two reds and one white is about $0.75010142$ and of zero reds and three whites $0.24989858$, and after $29$ rounds the probability of one red and one white is $1$, so after $30$ rounds the probability of zero reds and one white is $1$.